# What do the parameters v and k in this YUI function refer to?

Tags: javascript, html, yui

```
YUI().use('dd-constrain', 'dd-proxy', 'dd-drop', function(Y) {
var lis = Y.Node.all('#listContainer ul li');//Get a NodeList of all li
lis.each(function(v,k) {
    var dd = new Y.DD.Drag({
        node:v,
        //Make it Drop target and pass this config to the Drop constructor
        //Not sure what this actually means
        target: {
            padding: '0 0 0 20'
        }
    }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDProxy, {
        //Don't move the node at the end of the drag
        moveOnEnd:false
    }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDConstrained, {
        //Keep it inside the #listContainer node
        constrain2node: '#listContainer'
    });
});
```

What do the paramters v and k refer to in the function?  It seems like v is the node, which could make sense, but then what is k?  Also, what does the "target: " portion do?

Comment: `value` and `key`, common when iterating over an array/object

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering what the value and key are in YUI nodes

Comment: You're iterating over `lis.each`, which are the list item elements in `#listContainer`. So `value` would be the `li` and the `key` would likely be a numerical index, `0,1,2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/NodeList.html#method_each), you'll be passed:

- Current node instance
- Node index (position in the list)
- The Nodelist itself

Your callback is only defining two arguments, which is fine

Answer (score 0):

The current value of the item in the loop, you got all the `<li>` before so probably will be the content/value of each `<li>`